# Adding reference to structures into C# lists

Tags: c#

Trying to keep my C# code optimized, I found that if I have a list of structure elements, each insertion would be a full copy - something that I would like to avoid.

In C++ I would simply keep a list of pointers and so I was wondering if I can do the same using C#, maybe by having the list as a list of references to the structure.
Unfortunately the structure cannot be turned into a class as it is part of the XNA library (Vector3, Matrix, etc...)
In any case - how would the format and usage look like if it's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a class that stores the structure.  Be very careful with premature optimization, arrays of pointers have lousy cache locality.

Comment: How much larger than a reference is the structure? Structures are supposed to be small; if they are so much larger than a reference that the copying time is your bottleneck then you might not be wanting to use a struct in the first place. Can you give more details?

Comment: Well, reference only takes 4bytes, so anything bigger than a float or integer is already bigger than that.    If you do the math, even if I am very modest and only stores a simple Vector4, the ratio is already 4:1, and this is nothing close to a large structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, basically. Options:

- use a class (you've already said you can't)
- box it
- write a class that wraps it (essentially, manual boxing)
- use an array, and access it **only** directly in the array by index (without copying into a variable); this is then talking directly to the item in the array (no copy)

As an example of the last;

```
if(arr[idx].X == 20) SomeMethod(ref arr[idx]);
```

Both the .X, and any usage within SomeMethod, are accessing the value directly in the array, not a copy. This is only possible with vectors (arrays), not lists.

One reason a list of refs to structs isn't possible: it would allow you I store, in the list, the address of a variable on the stack; the array usually outlives the variable on the stack, so that would be ludicrously unsafe

Comment: I remember some of the fun bugs you can create by unintentionally storing references to structures on the stack in C.

Comment: You can do a great deal of things in C that you really should not do.

Comment: @Ramhound, particularly when a hacker discovers what you shouldn't have done and injects data into your corrupted stack to hijack the application.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create storeable references to structures in C#, but you could create a reference type wrapper for your value type.  That said, the overhead associated with copying the memory is not going to be high for a small structure.  Has your profiling shown that this is a problem?

---

Below is an example of a value type wrapped in a reference type.  Note that this only works if all access to a particular value is through the wrapping reference type.  This violates standard rules of insulation (because of the public field), but this is a bit of a special case.

```
public sealed class Reference<T>
    where T: struct
{
    public T Value;

    public Reference(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Another thing worth noting is that the Reference wrapper itself can take on the value null, though its contents are non-nullable.  You can also add implicit or explicit conversion operators to make this more transparent, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If the structs are made of simple types then you can make an array of pointers. Yes pointers in C# are very useful for cases like yours. There are limitations though. The original structures have to be stored in an `Array` and not a `List<>`. Look at the example below compiled with `unsafe` build flag.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Vec3
{
    public double X, Y, Z;
    public double Mag { get { return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z); } }
}

public unsafe class Vec3ArrayProxy
{
    Vec3*[] ptr = null; //internal array of pointers

    public Vec3ArrayProxy(Vec3[] array)
    {
        ptr = new Vec3*[array.Length]; //allocate array
        fixed (Vec3* src = array) //src holds pointer from source array
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                ptr[i] = &src[i]; //take address of i-th element
            }                
        }
    }

    public Vec3ArrayProxy(Vec3ArrayProxy other)
    {
        //just use all the existing pointers
        ptr = (Vec3*[])other.ptr.Clone();
        //or I could say:
        //ptr = other.ptr;
    }
    // Access values with index
    public Vec3 this[int index]
    {
        get { return *ptr[index]; }
        set { *ptr[index] = value; }
    }
    public int Count { get { return ptr.Length; } }
    // Access the array of pointers
    public Vec3*[] PtrArray { get { return ptr; } }
    // Copy the values of original array into new array
    public Vec3[] ToArrayCopy()
    {
        Vec3[] res = new Vec3[ptr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = *ptr[i];
        }
        return res;
    }

}


unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = 10; //size of array

        // Allocate array in memory
        Vec3[] array = new Vec3[N];

        // Assign values into array
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new Vec3() { X = i, Y = 0, Z = 0 };
        }

        //Build proxy to array (with pointers)
        Vec3Array A = new Vec3Array(array);
        // Reference the same pointers as A
        Vec3Array B = new Vec3Array(A); 

        // Change the original array
        array[4].X = -4;

        // Or change via a copy
        A.PtrArray[5]->Y = -5;  

        // Or assign a new value
        B[0] = B[9];            

        // Show contents of array via proxy A
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-6}|{1,6}|{2,6}|{3,6}|{4,6}", 
            "i", "X", "Y", "Z", "Mag");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,6}|{1,6:F2}|{2,6:F2}|{3,6:F2}|{4,6:F3}", 
                i + 1, A[i].X, A[i].Y, A[i].Z, A[i].Mag);
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry for the long code, but I wanted to show all the features of struct pointers. The reason that `List<>` will not work is because you cannot take a pointer to a list element. If you really really really must use a `List<>`, then extract the array from the private field `_items` with the following code:

```
    static T[] ExtractArray(List<T> list)
    {
        //list.TrimExcess();
        var t = list.GetType();
        var items = t.GetField("_items", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return items.GetValue(list) as T[];
    }
```

Crude as it may be, it works and once you have made the reflection on `List<>` once, you can cache the results in a static field and only call the `items.GetValue(list)` each time.

Comment: This does not pin the location of the array beyond the scope of creating the proxy and can therefore crash is horrible ways when the array is moved during GC.

Comment: @DanBryant - interesting. How can I force the GC to collect the original array and demo the crash?

Comment: You might try allocating a bunch of small objects just before allocating the array, then reference them after allocating the array (so the GC knows they had to remain rooted for a while), then stop referencing them and force a GC with GC.Collect.  I believe this will trigger a heap compaction of Gen0 and possibly even promote the array to Gen1; either of these should move the array in memory.  Note that it's not guaranteed to crash; it may just silently corrupt memory.  If you allocate a large enough array in the newly GCd space, then access your original pointers, you might observe it.

Comment: On a side note, it doesn't actually 'collect' the array, it merely relocates it in memory, hijacks all running threads and replaces any (managed) references so that they don't realize it has moved.